# Reference for Proof of the statement: "A graph G is planar if and only if every subdivision of G is planar."

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I have seen the theorem

> A graph G is planar if and only if every subdivision of G is planar.

stated in many places. Often it is posed as an assignment or as part of a lecture.

I would like to reference the theorem and its proof in a paper. What should I use as my reference? Is there a textbook or article that comes to mind?

Comment: I'd not reference it at all. A result as elementary as this, in a research paper, can safely be assumed to be known by the intended reader.

Comment: Draw the graph in the plane. Subdivide it. It is still planar, is it not? :)

Comment: While I agree that the result is elementary, I can't assume that the audience of my paper is familiar with it. I would include the proof itself if not for space limitations.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: what you say is true, and yet this misses the point: the only slightly nontrivial aspect of the OP's statement is the implication '$G$ **non**-planar'$\Rightarrow$'every subdivision of $G$ still **non**-planar'. Informally put: one cannot make a graph planar by subdividing edges.

Comment: @PeterHeinig Isn't the correct implication "G non-planar $\Rightarrow$ THERE EXISTS a subdivision which is non-planar"? And this is trivial, take $G$ as a subdivision of itself.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks for catching that. In fact, *each* of the three comments at 2018-02-20 16:40:35Z, 2018-02-20 17:15:15Z, 2018-02-20 17:29:17Z managed to *miss the point*, mine included. The slightly nontrivial aspect is the 'only if' in the OP, and to prove it one has to actually work with whatever explicit definition of 'plane embedding' one uses. Given an arbitrary subdivision of $G$, to use the hypothesis (i.e. the LHS in the OP), one has to consider $G$ itself, then obtain a plane embedding by virtue of the hypothesis (one has no say in what plane embedding one get), and then [...]

Comment: [...] the point-set topology starts: one then has to argue (and this *cannot be done informally in words here, since no formalism has been set up*) that all the subdivision vertices can be inserted *into the specific plane embedding*. This is easy to argue, even if *countably*-many subdivision points are permitted, but again, if one really wants to *prove* this then one has to speak about embeddings in detail. I think there's no need to delete the comments; it is quite a spectacle when three people in a row miss the point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what comes to mind as a citable reference is Proposition 10.3 in

> J.A. Bondy, U.S.R. Murty, *Graph Theory*, Graduate Texts in Mathematics 244, Springer 2008, ISBN: 978-1-84628-969-9

Comment: Thanks for providing a possible reference, but I have read the section that you mention, but the authors mention it only as a proposition and do not present proof.